# How to disable ColdFusion 10 ORM Logging

Tags: windows, coldfusion, log4j

Early this morning I was woken up by an alert that my CF 10 server (windows) was running out of HDD space.  It appeared my hibernatesql.log file was upwards of 20GB!  First, I checked my Application.cfc and confirmed logging was disabled...

```
<cfset this.ormsettings.logsql = false/>
```

Then I started Googling and discovered there was at least a way to keep the log file from getting so big.  You have to modify your /lib/log4j.properties like so...

```
# HibernateConsole is set to be a ConsoleAppender for Hibernate message  using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.HIBERNATECONSOLE= org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HIBERNATECONSOLE.File=C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/logs/hibernatesql.log
log4j.appender.HIBERNATECONSOLE.Append=true
log4j.appender.HIBERNATECONSOLE.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.HIBERNATECONSOLE.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.HIBERNATECONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HIBERNATECONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] HIBERNATE %-5p - %m%n%
```

This ensures I'm using no more than 15MB of HDD space for my hibernate logging.  However, I really want to disable it or at least set the log level to errors only.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to cheat, you set up a scheduled job that overwrites your log file with an empty file every day.  As far as logging hibernate errors is concerned, are they not included in the exception.log along with all the other ColdFusion errors?

Comment: Take a look at the other settings in `log4j.properties`.  If I remember my log4j stuff, the sql level is set to debug: `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, HIBERNATECONSOLE`. Try changing it to `ERROR`.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off logging, add this line to your log4j.properties file

> log4j.appender.HIBERNATECONSOLE.Threshold=OFF

Other than OFF, the set of possible threshold levels is: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it's a [bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3687147), but turns out it is not.

> Hibernate uses log4j for its logging and you can completely control
>   its logging (including SQL) by modifying the log4j.properties.
>   log4j.properties is present under /lib directory. Please note
>   that you don’t need to do any application specific setting for this.

http://www.rupeshk.org/blog/index.php/2009/07/coldfusion-orm-how-to-log-sql/